# JQuery Navigation Sticky

Tags: jquery, html, css, navigation, sticky

I tryed to make my Navigation Sticky..but didn'T work.. here my JQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var stickyNavTop = $('nav').offset().top;
    var stickyNav = function(){
        var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
        if (scrollTop > stickyNavTop) {
            $('nav').addClass('sticky');
        } else {
            $('nav').removeClass('sticky');
        }
    };
    stickyNav();
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        stickyNav();
    });
});
```

and the used css-definitions:

```
.sticky {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
}
nav {               
    background: url('bilder/bg_nav.png') no-repeat;
    width: 800px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 40px;
}
```

you can see all at [link](http://nitram0598.pf-control.de/)

thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't find the jQuery library in your html, you should put this snippet in the `<head>` section of your html to make your jQuery code work:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

your need to also include the jquery framework, ie http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.js

I have an example here for you to follow.

http://jsfiddle.net/